# Entering Zodiac Signs into Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I want to be able to quickly and easily enter the Zodiac signs (via their Unicode characters) into Visual Studio. I can copy+paste them in just fine, but that becomes tiring when needing to write code for a project that uses them extensively. I want something a bit faster that doesn't require paging back and forth between a sheet with copy+paste.

I tried using the Alt+Code entry but, for some reason, it enters the wrong characters into Visual Studio, despite working fine in most other applications I have tried. For example, when I tried to enter Aries '♈' it gives me 'H' (Alt+9800).

I read in a few places online that Unicode characters can be entered by typing their numeric value and then pressing Alt+X, but this seems to have no effect in my instance of Visual Studio. I thought that perhaps that key-binding wasn't enabled, but I had no idea what such a key binding would be called in order to rebind it.

So, my question to you, wise Stack Overflow, is this: **What's the fastest and easiest way to repeatedly enter the Zodiac Unicode characters into Visual Studio?**

Comment: Not clear what you do :( Are you entering those symbols into UI elements (forms, dialogs, etc), or are you using them in your text code (C++? C#? VB?). Which part of Visual Studio are you talking about? The answer would depend on that. Besides, the UNICODE character for Aries is U+2648: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2648/index.htm

Comment: I'm using the characters in chars in a C# application.  '♈' is a valid and recognized char. 

You're correct that the Unicode value for Aries is 2648, but that's not the Alt+Code. That is Alt+9800.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a faster solution to enter the characters as if I was typing a key on the keyboard. I even went as far as attempting to bind custom keys on my Razer peripheral devices, but they don't have a means to set "Enter character of choice" as a binding.

Ultimately, what I found was the fastest and easiest in this case, was to declare a public static class that includes const chars that are named appropriately and copy+paste the characters themselves in exactly once. Then, I simply allowed code-complete to handle using these in code.

It makes the code more verbose in every location that uses one of these chars, but does have the added benefit that, in the future if we were to decide that a different Aries character, for example, was preferable, we could change all of the characters globally from a single place without needing to find+replace-all.

```
public static class Zodiac
{
    public const char Aries = '♈';
    public const char Taurus = '♉';
    public const char Gemini = '♊';
    // ...
}
```